# I can't inset a node to bin search tree

Tags: c, insert, binary-search-tree

I want to write a `BST`,but the insert function doesn't work. Debugging it , I found that it was not inserting.

```
/* Binary Search Tree (BST).demo */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct treeNode{
    int data;
    struct treeNode* lChild;
    struct treeNode* rChild;
 } treeNode;

treeNode* createNode(){
        treeNode *nNode;
        nNode=(struct treeNode*)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
        nNode->data=0;
        nNode->lChild=NULL;
        nNode->rChild=NULL;

        return nNode;
}

void insert(treeNode* rt,int idata)
{
  if(rt==NULL){
    treeNode* nNode;
    nNode=createNode();
    nNode->data=idata;
    rt=nNode;
    rt->lChild=NULL;
    rt->rChild=NULL;
  }else{
    if(idata < rt->data)
        insert(rt->lChild,idata);
    else insert(rt->rChild,idata);

  }
}

int main()
{
    treeNode *root;
    root=(treeNode*)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
    root->data=15;
    root->lChild=NULL;
    root->rChild=NULL;

    insert(root,13);
    if(root->lChild==NULL)
          printf("root no l child\n");
     // printf("root lchild data :%d",root->lChild->data);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: use a reference to 'root' when you are passing it as an argument to the insert function.

Comment: but the root itself is a pointer,is there needs  a reference?

Comment: if you don't use reference to 'root', you would be passing it by "value" to the insert function. In that case, if you are creating a new node and assigning it to the 'root'(as you are doing here), this change won't be reflected outside the insert function, thus causing erroneous behavior.

Answer (score 2):

use this as the insert function :

```
void insert(treeNode** rt,int idata)
{
     if((*rt)==NULL)
     {
       treeNode* nNode;
       nNode=createNode();
       nNode->data=idata;
       *rt=nNode;
       (*rt)->lChild=NULL;
       (*rt)->rChild=NULL;
     }
     else
     {
         if(idata < (*rt)->data)
             insert(&((*rt)->lChild),idata);
         else 
             insert(&((*rt)->rChild),idata);
     }
}
```

and the insert function call in main() as:

```
insert(&root,13);
```

Comment: Thank you and I now understand that why there is *leftchild & *rightchild in struct of Node . Thanks @ Nithin Bhaskar

Comment: @michael_stackof no problem. have fun coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I usually implement it like this:

```
void insert(treeNode* rt, int idata) {
    // assert( rt != NULL );
    if(idata < rt->data){
        if( rt->lChild != NULL)
            insert(rt->lChild, idata);
        else {
            rt->lChild = createNode();
            rt->lChild->data = idata;
        }
    } else {
        if( rt->rChild != NULL)
            insert(rt->rChild, idata);
        else {
            rt->rChild = createNode();
            rt->rChild->data = idata;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Moreover, I prefer give an argument to `createNode()`

```
treeNode* createNode(int idata){
    // ...
    nNode->data = idata;
    // ...
}
```

So the `insert` will look like:

```
void insert(treeNode* rt, int idata) {
    // ...
            rt->lChild = createNode(idata);
    // ...
            rt->rChild = createNode(idata);
    // ...
}
```